# Parsing HTML with Node JS on Server Side

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to read `div` contents of an html file with node js on server without using the browser. I would like to be able to use jQuery operations as well.

More specifically, something like `content.find("div.t")`.

Is there a native way of doing this?

I tried to use `fs.readfilesync` to read the html file on the server and to get the content, but this gives me a string, not html that I can make jQuery operations on.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Should work in the Simplest way :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var htmlFileString = <valid html of some sort>;

var rootElement = $(htmlFileString);
rootElement.find('div.t');
```

Comment: I tried this as the following: 
let stringContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../pdf/LabReport1.html'), 'utf8');
var rootElement = $(stringContent);

I got the error:
'throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );'

Comment: Then I'll refer you to the possible duplicate mentioned on your questions comments. Seems to have worked out there with jsdom.

Comment: That's right. I did it with cheerio.